# C++/CLI/C# callbacks using virtual methods in interface

Tags: c#, c++, interface, callback, c++-cli

I'm trying to write a C# application that uses some old C++ code, which provides abstract classes that needs to be override to receive OnCallbacks. The way its done in C++ is the developer derived from a base class and overrides some methods if it wants to receive callbacks, quite normal.

Problem is, i need to be able to access those data in C#, so i wrote a C++/CLI bridge DLL hopefully to achieve that but to no avail. I've simplified my design here hopefully you get what i mean...

The C++ code (which hopefully i dont need to do much modification)

```
// C++ code
namespace ApiWrapperNet
{
    // abstract [interface] class
    class DataListener {
    public:
        virtual void OnMessage(const std::string& message) = 0;
    };

    // main class which provides 
    class DataWrapper {
    public:
        void Subscribe(const std::string& prod, DataListener* dimp)
        {
            dimp->OnMessage("Hello World");
        };
    };

    // implements our interface
    class DataListenerImpl : public DataListener {
    public:
        virtual void OnMessage(const std::string& message)
        {
            std::cout << message;   // here C++ works, displays Hello World
        }
    };
}
```

Now here is what i currently have for the C++/CLI (managed) code

```
// C++/CLI [glue code]
namespace ApiWrapperNet 
{
    public interface class IDataListener {
    public:
        virtual void OnMessage(System::String^ message) = 0;
    };

    public ref class DataWrapperDotNet {
    public:

        void Subscribe(System::String^ prod, IDataListener^ ptr)
        {
            // how to implement here ?!?
            // i want to call DataWrapper::Subscribe(prod, ptr);
            // by passing in the reference to my object so callback can be made
        };
    };
}
```

And finally, here is how I intend to use it in C# side, in a class that implements the interface

```
// C# code
namespace ApiWrapperNet 
{
    public class DataListenerImpl : IDataListener
    {
        public void OnMessage(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);     // should display Hello World
        }

        public DataListenerImpl()
        {
            var m = new DataWrapperDotNet();

            m.Subscribe("Product_Name", this);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: You must write an unmanaged version of DataListener (plain class, no ref).  Use `gcroot<DataWrapperDotNet>` to store a reference to the managed wrapper.  Create and initialize an instance of that class in the Subscribe() method, ready to be passed as the 2nd argument.  Store the IDataListener^ in a field for later use.   In its OnMessage() implementation use the gcroot to call a managed method in DataWrapperDotNet.  Which can then make the interface call through the stored IDataListener^.

Comment: =( unfortunately, i am still new to C++/CLI, i have no idea what all this means. can somebody be kind enough to provide an example? or solution..... thanks.